# how to adjust the default width of taglist window in vim

Tags: vim

The default width of taglist window is too narrow for me and sometimes I can't see the whole function name in the window so I'd like to adujct the width of the window. I know use `ctr-w >` or `ctr-w <` I can adjust the window manually , but really want to change the default value of the taglisst window. so how I can actually do it ? thansk in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
let Tlist_WinWidth = somenumber
```

Answer (score 0):

to set it percentage of the screen:

```
let g:Tlist_width = winwidth(0) * 10/100
```

it set the *taglist* 10 percent of screen.
for *tagbar* change it to: `let g:tagbar_width = winwidth(0) * 10/100`